# concurrent access issue while updating database name as parameters in power bi report

Tags: powerbi

I'm working in power bi report. I have Pro licence. I have created a report using the database name as parameter. I'm passing the parameter from c# to the power bi report using UpdateParametrs api. This is working fine. Based on the parameter passed its changing the dataset dynamically. But when concurrent users are accessing the report from embedded app then both users are seeing the same database's data. How can I resolve this? What is the best approach to connect dynamic database for multi-tenant applications?

Any help on this will be much appreciated!.